# How to implement this in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

This is what I wish to do using MySQL alone: (without PHP)

PHP Code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select f2 from t1 where f1=constant limit L");

while( $data = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
  mysql_query("update t2 set f4=f4-1 where f3={$data[0]} limit 1");
```

If you don't know PHP:

```
select f2 from t1 where f1=constant limit L;

for each f2 (from above result) as F:
  update t2 set f4=f4-1 where f3=F limit 1;
```

How to implement this in MySQL?

**Details:**

There can be duplicate values in the output of first select, and for each of the duplicates, the update statement will be run. So if value '123' occurs thrice in the output of first select then f4 will be updated to f4-3 where f3=123.

'L' is the number of times the "f1=constant" condition is satisfied in table 't1'; this number is known before hence used as a limit.

limit 1 is used because values in field 'f3' are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Use this query, and supply the missing parameters:

```
UPDATE t2 SET f4 = f4 - 1

WHERE f3 IN (SELECT f2 FROM t1 WHERE f1 = ? LIMIT ?);
```

---

If you want to have `t2.f4` modified for each row in `f2` that matches (given that `f2.t1` is not unique) then this should work:

```
UPDATE t2, t1 SET t2.f4 = t2.f4 - 1
WHERE t2.f3 = t1.f2
  AND t1.f1 = ?;
```

Comment: If the select statement inside parenthesis gives duplicate values  then will update be done for each of the duplicate values?

Comment: And how to tell MySQL here that for each "where in", it'll be finding only one record in t2? (As I'm doing in my question)

Comment: @user1444680 If there is a unique index on `t2.f3` then you don't need a `LIMIT` clause on the update, since only one row can be updated per value.  `WHERE ... IN` will ignore duplicate values in the subquery, but you can change the subquery to `SELECT DISTINCT` if this makes you feel better.  (That change will not alter the behavior of the query.)

Comment: But the unique index will slow down inserts? Sir I've mentioned in my question (1st point under Details) that I wish that for every duplicate value, the update must be repeated. What do you suggest?

Comment: If there are duplicate values in `t2.f3` then those will be affected by this query too, which seems to be what you want anyway.

Comment: _"WHERE ... IN will ignore duplicate values in the subquery"_ I don't want this to happen. Example:- table t1(f1,f2):(1,2),(1,2) ; table t2(f3,f4):(2,4) . My PHP code is changing f4 from 4 to 2. This is what I want. Your query is changing f4 to 3 (instead of 2).

Comment: I've added another query to my answer.  Try that one.

Comment: No, it's also changing f4 to 3, instead of 2. In my previous comment I forgot to mention that in the example inside the comment, I was taking the constant value to be 1, i.e. `where f1=1`.